# How to use celery to run SQL and get returned result from DB?

Tags: python, flask, celery, flask-sqlalchemy

I am using Flask, Celery, Redis and Mysql to build website. Now I am facing one problem. I want to send every SQL query to celery and once job is done I then get query result from celery.result.
Here is part of my code:

Manage.py

```
import os
from app import create_app, db
from app.models import Users, Items
from flask.ext.script import Manager, Shell
from flask.ext.migrate import Migrate, MigrateCommand


app = create_app(os.getenv('FLASK_CONFIG') or 'default')
app.app_context().push()
manager = Manager(app)
migrate = Migrate(app, db)

def make_shell_context():
    return dict(app=app, db=db, Users=Users, Items=Items)

manager.add_command("shell", Shell(make_context=make_shell_context))
manager.add_command('db', MigrateCommand)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    manager.run()
```

query.py

```
from .models import Items, Users
from sqlalchemy import desc
from app import create_celery_app


celery = create_celery_app()

@celery.task
def user_query(id):
    return Users.query.filter_by(id = id).first()
```

view.py

```
from ..query import user_query
...
userresult = user_query.delay(1)
```

main.py

```
from flask import Blueprint
main = Blueprint('main', __name__)
from . import views, errors
```

app.py

```
from flask import Flask
from flask.ext.bootstrap import Bootstrap
from flask.ext.moment import Moment
from config import config, Config
from celery import Celery
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
import os


bootstrap = Bootstrap()
moment = Moment()
db = SQLAlchemy()


def create_app(config_name):
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object(config[config_name])
    config[config_name].init_app(app)

    bootstrap.init_app(app)
    moment.init_app(app)
    db.init_app(app)

    from main import main as main_blueprint
    app.register_blueprint(main_blueprint)
    return app

def create_celery_app(app=None):
    app = app or create_app(os.getenv('FLASK_CONFIG') or 'default')
    celery = Celery(__name__, broker=app.config['CELERY_BROKER_URL'], include=['app.query'])
    celery.conf.update(app.config)
    TaskBase = celery.Task

    class ContextTask(TaskBase):
        abstract = True
        def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            with app.app_context():
                return TaskBase.__call__(self, *args, **kwargs)

    celery.Task = ContextTask
    return celery
```

When I run celery worker I get error:

```
File "/home/yx/Documents/flasky/venv/bin/celery", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/home/yx/Documents/flasky/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/__main__.py", line 30, in main
    main()
  File "/home/yx/Documents/flasky/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/bin/celery.py", line 81, in main
    cmd.execute_from_commandline(argv)
  File "/home/yx/Documents/flasky/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/bin/celery.py", line 770, in execute_from_commandline
    super(CeleryCommand, self).execute_from_commandline(argv)))
  File "/home/yx/Documents/flasky/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/bin/base.py", line 309, in execute_from_commandline
    argv = self.setup_app_from_commandline(argv)
  File "/home/yx/Documents/flasky/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/bin/base.py", line 469, in setup_app_from_commandline
    self.app = self.find_app(app)
  File "/home/yx/Documents/flasky/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/bin/base.py", line 489, in find_app
    return find_app(app, symbol_by_name=self.symbol_by_name)
  File "/home/yx/Documents/flasky/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/app/utils.py", line 229, in find_app
    sym = symbol_by_name(app, imp=imp)
  File "/home/yx/Documents/flasky/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/bin/base.py", line 492, in symbol_by_name
    return symbol_by_name(name, imp=imp)
  File "/home/yx/Documents/flasky/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/utils/__init__.py", line 96, in symbol_by_name
    module = imp(module_name, package=package, **kwargs)
  File "/home/yx/Documents/flasky/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/utils/imports.py", line 101, in import_from_cwd
    return imp(module, package=package)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/home/yx/Documents/flasky/app/query.py", line 6, in <module>
    celery = create_celery_app()
  File "/home/yx/Documents/flasky/app/__init__.py", line 29, in create_celery_app
    app = app or create_app(os.getenv('FLASK_CONFIG') or 'default')
  File "/home/yx/Documents/flasky/app/__init__.py", line 24, in create_app
    from main import main as main_blueprint
  File "/home/yx/Documents/flasky/app/main/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from . import views, errors
  File "/home/yx/Documents/flasky/app/main/views.py", line 7, in <module>
    from ..query import user_query
ImportError: cannot import name user_query
```

But user_query is from query.py, so does anyone know if I miss something?
Thank you.

Comment: If you're returning the results from the view, using Celery isn't going to gain you anything.

Comment: It doesn't look like a Celery problem, but an import problem in `views.py`. Change the import to `from .query import user_query`

Comment: @dirn I just call delay in view.py. So you mean I should return result in query.py?

Comment: @jumbopap I just updated view.py and you can see the original from statement. This works if I don't use celery,  so I get confused

Comment: Why are you trying to do this?  Celery is for background tasks, ones where the person submitting the request doesn't require/expect an instant response.